# PyQt5 draggable icons from a listview to another

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qmainwindow, qlistview

I struggle to drag and drop icons from a listview (ViewMode set to IconMode) to another. It's similar to what I've found in the [docs](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-draganddrop-draggableicons-example.html).

[image: listviews example]

**Scenario**: A user drags the QIcon 1 from ListView 1 and drops it to ListView 2. ListView 2 should add QIcon 1 to its model. Moreover I want to do some background work when a **specific** QIcon is added to ListView 2. How do I know that QIcon 1 was dropped to ListView 2 and not QIcon 2?

mainwindow (sets up the layout, loads the images into listview 1):

```
class Ui_MainWindow(object):
...
    def loadImages(self):
        model = QStandardItemModel()
        images = Path("images").glob("*.*")
        for image in images:
            item = QStandardItem()
            item.setIcon(QIcon(str(image)))
            model.appendRow(item)

        self.listView1.setModel(model)
```

listview 1:

```
class ListView1(QListView):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setAcceptDrops(False)
        self.setViewMode(QtWidgets.QListView.IconMode)
        self.setEditTriggers(QAbstractItemView.NoEditTriggers)
        self.setIconSize(QSize(50, 50))
        self.setResizeMode(QtWidgets.QListView.Adjust)
        self.setDragDropMode(QAbstractItemView.DragOnly)
```

listview 2:

```
class ListView2(QListView):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setViewMode(QtWidgets.QListView.IconMode)
        self.setDragDropMode(QAbstractItemView.DropOnly)
        self.setIconSize(QSize(50, 50))
        self.setAcceptDrops(True)

    def dragEnterEvent(self, event):
        event.accept()

    def dragMoveEvent(self, event):
        event.accept()

    def dropEvent(self, event):
        event.accept()
        event.setDropAction(QtCore.Qt.MoveAction)
        event.acceptProposedAction()
```

How can I drag and drop an icon from listview 1 to listview 2 and access its properties?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not necessary to overwrite dragEnterEvent, dragMoveEvent or dropEvent since those implementations already exist and work correctly, the example you point out is for other types of widgets that do not have those events implemented.

```
from pathlib import Path
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class LListView(QtWidgets.QListView):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(LListView, self).__init__(parent)
        self.model = QtGui.QStandardItemModel(self)
        self.setModel(self.model)

        self.setAcceptDrops(False)
        self.setViewMode(QtWidgets.QListView.IconMode)
        self.setEditTriggers(QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.NoEditTriggers)
        self.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(50, 50))
        self.setResizeMode(QtWidgets.QListView.Adjust)
        self.setDragDropMode(QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.DragOnly)

class RListView(QtWidgets.QListView):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(RListView, self).__init__(parent)
        self.model = QtGui.QStandardItemModel(self)
        self.setModel(self.model)

        self.setAcceptDrops(True)
        self.setViewMode(QtWidgets.QListView.IconMode)
        self.setEditTriggers(QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.NoEditTriggers)
        self.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(50, 50))
        self.setResizeMode(QtWidgets.QListView.Adjust)
        self.setDragDropMode(QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.DropOnly)


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)

        central_widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.l_view = LListView()
        self.r_view = RListView()

        self.setCentralWidget(central_widget)
        lay = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(central_widget)
        lay.addWidget(self.l_view)
        lay.addWidget(self.r_view)
        self.loadImages()

    def loadImages(self):
        images = Path("images").glob("*.*")
        for image in images:
            item = QtGui.QStandardItem()
            item.setIcon(QtGui.QIcon(str(image)))
            self.l_view.model.appendRow(item)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**Update:**

If you want to add an identifier this can be done through a role that you pass when creating the item, and then in the `dropEvent()` get all the roles, then get the role you want and through it the identifier:

```
from pathlib import Path
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class LListView(QtWidgets.QListView):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(LListView, self).__init__(parent)
        self.m_model = QtGui.QStandardItemModel(self)
        self.setModel(self.m_model)

        self.setAcceptDrops(False)
        self.setViewMode(QtWidgets.QListView.IconMode)
        self.setEditTriggers(QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.NoEditTriggers)
        self.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(50, 50))
        self.setResizeMode(QtWidgets.QListView.Adjust)
        self.setDragDropMode(QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.DragOnly)

class RListView(QtWidgets.QListView):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(RListView, self).__init__(parent)
        self.m_model = QtGui.QStandardItemModel(self)
        self.setModel(self.m_model)

        self.setAcceptDrops(True)
        self.setEditTriggers(QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.NoEditTriggers)
        self.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(50, 50))
        self.setResizeMode(QtWidgets.QListView.Adjust)
        self.setDragDropMode(QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.DropOnly)

    def dropEvent(self, event):
        last_row_count = self.model().rowCount()
        super(RListView, self).dropEvent(event)
        # check if an item is added
        if self.model().rowCount() > last_row_count:
            md = event.mimeData()
            fmt = "application/x-qabstractitemmodeldatalist"
            if md.hasFormat(fmt):
                encoded = md.data(fmt)
                stream = QtCore.QDataStream(encoded, QtCore.QIODevice.ReadOnly)
                datas = []
                item = {}
                while not stream.atEnd():
                    row = stream.readInt32()
                    column = stream.readInt32()
                    map_items = stream.readInt32()
                    for i in range(map_items):
                        key = stream.readInt32()
                        value = QtCore.QVariant()
                        stream >> value
                        item[QtCore.Qt.ItemDataRole(key)] = value
                    datas.append(item)
                for data in datas:
                    identifier = data[QtCore.Qt.UserRole+1].value()
                    print("identifier: ", identifier)


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)

        central_widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.l_view = LListView()
        self.r_view = RListView()

        self.setCentralWidget(central_widget)
        lay = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(central_widget)
        lay.addWidget(self.l_view)
        lay.addWidget(self.r_view)
        self.loadImages()

    def loadImages(self):
        images = Path("images").glob("*.*")
        for i, image in enumerate(images):
            item = QtGui.QStandardItem()
            identifier = "img_{:06d}".format(i+1)
            item.setData(identifier, QtCore.Qt.UserRole+1)
            item.setIcon(QtGui.QIcon(str(image)))
            self.l_view.m_model.appendRow(item)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: if I don't override those methods, how can I listen to a drop event? For example I want to know which icon was dropped so that I can remove it from LListView and do some other things in the background with the icon. So I need a path or name of the icon

Comment: @momo a QIcon is no longer a file so it has no name, a QIcon is data loaded in RAM so I recommend you rethink what you want.

Comment: I see. So if I want to display images in a grid (and not as QIcons) with drag and drop functionality, I can't take a QListView and have to implement it myself with a QGridLayout and QPixmap?

Comment: QPixmap is also data in RAM, for example make a program that shows an image from a .png, then delete it and you will see that even though the image of the program is maintained, the .png file only serves as the initial source of the image. You could be more concise with what you want, what functionality do you want? Do you want to have a QGridLayout with QLabels and drag the images and set them as QPixmap of the QLabels?

Comment: I want to display images in a nxn grid view and drag the images to another 1xn grid view. Therefore my approach was to use two QListViews with a ViewMode set to IconMode, as it seems to resize perfectly according to the window size. But with this approach I am not able to know which QIcon (im my case image) has been dropped because I can't get the name or path of the dropped QIcon. According to your answer I assumed that I have to go with QGridLayout and QLabels?

Comment: @momo I commented that about QLabel and QGridLayout because you did it, I do not really understand what you want and that you have the name of the icons, the icons have no name, the files do, QIcon is different to file. You could clearly explain your question, I also think that this question is very different from the question in this post, so I recommend posting a new question, on the other hand if my answer helps you do not forget to mark it as correct.

Comment: I added an image and a scenario for clarification. Hope this helps

Comment: @momo What I am understanding is that you want to obtain an identifier, as for example according to your graph: "QIcon 1" is associated with 0, "QIcon 2" is associated with 1, etc, and then get that identifier in QListView2 , I am right?

Comment: Exactly! But the identifier should rather be a string than a number. Maybe there is a possibility to wrap the QIcon and associate a string?

Comment: @momo And how would that chain be? For example for "QIcon 1" what would the identifier be?

Comment: example for an identifier: "img_000001" or "img_000002"